# Log4j 2.16.0 not generating log file in JBoss EAP 7.3.0

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, log4j2, jboss-eap-7

My application is using Spring Boot and Apache Camel and deployed in JBoss EAP 7.3.0. In the application, logs are correctly generating to a log file when using log4j 1.2.17 but not getting generated when using log4j 2.16.0. The pom.xml is as below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>GroupID</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArtifactID</artifactId>
    <version>Version</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <env.camel.version>2.25.1</env.camel.version>
        <spring.boot-version>2.3.3.RELEASE</spring.boot-version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Spring-Boot and Camel BOM -->
    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.16.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.16.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${env.camel.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-swagger-java-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-base64</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-naming-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Build Configurations -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-war</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                            <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                            <webResources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </webResources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Another type of pom.xml with spring-boot-starter-parent that I tried with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>GroupID</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArtifactID</artifactId>
    <version>Version</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

log4j2-spring.xml which is in classpath is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="home">C:\\</Property>
        <Property name="interface-name">SomeDirectory</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger">
            <FileName>C:\\SomeDirectory\\Test.log</FileName>
            <FilePattern>C:\\SomeDirectory\\archive\\Test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}-%i.log</FilePattern>
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                 <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB" />
                 <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="fileLogger" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.springframework" level="info" additivity="false">
          <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml which is under webapp -> WEB-INF is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: "what I am doing wrong here?!" 1. set `log4j2.version=2.16.0` property (this will fix recently discovered vulnerabilities). 2..remove the (useless) log4j-dependencyManagement. 3. (a) Or name your logging config file to `log4j2.xml` or (b.) set the `log4j2.configurationFile`((env)property) to the according name

Comment: The pom.xml that I used did not had spring-boot-starter parent where we had to maintain all the dependencies ourselves. I have also used the one with spring-boot-starter-parent and modified the question with another pom.xml used. Also tried by modifying the name of log4j-spring.xml to log4j.xml but no luck. All these are working when the application is run as standalone jar, that means I may need to exclude some more jboss modules

Comment: Is your deployment using log4j 2 loggers?

Comment: I did not get it exactly, I have specified log4j2 in pom.xml and also log4j2.xml. Also log4j-api-2.16.0.jar and log4j-core-2.16.0.jar are present as maven dependency after build. This is working when run as a fat jar. Does anything else needs to be done?

Comment: Another point I found that if log4j.properties is included in the project, the log is getting generated in folder when deployed in jboss. So I guess that it is still using log4j 1.x from somewhere but the project does not contain any log4j 1.x Maven dependencies